# Verification email not sent for custom route get Route [verification.verify] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am creating User from my custom user route and i am not using default register route now after doing some R&D i get this method **sendEmailVerificationNotification()**

```
 $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
 $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
```

but now on using this method after user save i get error **Route [verification.verify] not defined**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **Laravel 8**  documentation of **[The Email Verification Handler](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification#the-email-verification-handler)**,  You need to define `verification.verify` route :

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
    $request->fulfill();
    return redirect('/home');
})->middleware(['auth', 'signed'])->name('verification.verify');
```

If you're using `laravel/ui`, then :

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply its working i just missed  in routes file
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);