# Laravel 9 Route [verification.verify] not defined

Tags: laravel-9, email-verification, mailtrap

I am trying to do email verification with mailtrap and laravel. I did it with official laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/verification. I did it step by step except for the two last steps which I currently don't need. I connected my .env with mailtrap and in MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS I used the same email adress as I have setup in mailtrap. I forgot to mention that I have registration and login setup with Auth and I didn't wrote them manually.

But when I tried to register, after filling the information needed in registration and clicking on registrate showed up error Route [verification.verify] not defined. I searched a lot and found this three articles: [Verification email not sent for custom route get Route [verification.verify] not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443500/verification-email-not-sent-for-custom-route-get-route-verification-verify-not) , https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/message-route-verificationverify-not-defined , https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/resolve-verificationverify-not-define

I think that the first two solutions should be included in documentation, which I implement and I don't understand the third one. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). We need to see the relevant parts of your code, and your debugging efforts - for eg, the obvious question is do you have a route named `verification.verify`?  Show us the part of `web.php` which defines that route.  Does it show up when you do `php artisan route:list`?  Are you caching routes, and if so have you cleared the cache? There is not enough info here for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: I am really sorry I was struggling with this few days, but after reading your answer I cleared my cache with few different commands and everything runs perfectly now. I think I tried to clean the cache with one command so this is url to website if somebody is having the same issue: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-clear-cache-laravel-using-artisan-command-mohsin-khan… I didn't write parts of my code, because I just used the same as are in the documentation, but I know that I have problem with making these questions. So thank you for your effort and time.